# VB 2010 Create an app without Framework

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Hello and thanks in Advance,
I've created an app in VB 2010 Express and I want to send it some clients that probably don't have .Net Framework 4. I can include in the setup to download it and install it however I want to explore my options before that.

1) Is there any way to create a lighter version of .Net Framework 4 that provides only the references used in the project ?

2) If not : some1 posted here that VB 6 doesn't need Framework. Is there any easy way to transfer my project from VB 2010 to VB 6 without having to start anew ?

Thanks again.

Comment: 1) No, you cannot create your own Framework version.  That would result in multiple versions of partial installs on systems and something the Framework concept avoids.  2) Depends on your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Specifically about transfering the project from vb 2010 to 6, I wanna ask how is it possible to copy the Visual part (The form with Buttons etc).

Comment: `I can include in the setup...`  actually you cant/dont.  Your users would get the framework from Microsoft.   It is actually pretty easy and seamless.  Probably better than going *backwards* from VB2010 to VB1998

Comment: That's what I meant. However, as I've said I need to see the alternatives first.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is there any way to create a lighter version of .Net Framework 4
>   that provides only the references used in the project ?

No, you cannot cherry-pick modules you want. .Net comes as a whole package. Now, that being said, you can ***target*** a lighter version of the .Net 4.0 Framework called [.NET Framework 4 Client Profile](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17113)

> 2) If not : some1 posted here that VB 6 doesn't need Framework. Is
>   there any easy way to transfer my project from VB 2010 to VB 6 without
>   having to start anew ?

There is no automated way to downgrade from VB2010 to VB6. Keep in mind, VB6 is a 17 year old unsupported programming language.

> I want to explore my options

1. Ask your clients to download the .Net 4.0 Framework
2. Target a version of .Net that is already installed on your client's machines. (.Net 4.0 is installed automatically as a windows update and [Windows 7 ships with .Net 3.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#History))
3. Include the [.Net 4.0 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718) in your installer.